# gcloud run deploy stuck at Routing traffic

Tags: gcloud

So today I started deploying some stuff to gclod and i got the usually process:

```
⠶ Building and deploying... Recreating retired Revision.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  ✓ Uploading sources...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  ✓ Building Container... Logs are available at [https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/4ee7f621-c548-4630-acbc-6bcd7daa3275?project=638685146920].                                                                                                                                                        
  ✓ Creating Revision...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  ⠶ Routing traffic...
```

But the unusual thing is that the Routing traffic took forever and after some time i got:

```
Deployment failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
ERROR: gcloud crashed (WaitException): last_result=<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.run.condition.Conditions object at 0x7f179f99c2b0>, last_retrial=1326, time_passed_ms=1799923,time_to_wait=1000
```

Comment: The deployment command failed after waiting 30 minutes. My suggestion is to try again as this might be a transient error or one that Google resolves quickly. If you continue to see this problem, create a bug report on [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).

Comment: the issue appears only on  --region us-central i tried with another one it works. hopefully they resolve quick

Comment: I have a similar issue: cloud build cannot to finish deploying to cloud run. After being stuck in routing for a long time it would give up. Then an error shows up in the console UI: "... not ready and cannot serve traffic. Waiting to reconcile Revision. Resource readiness deadline exceeded." My region is northamerica-northeast1.

Comment: fml same problem. my coworker can deploy fine.

Comment: we currently have this problem on europe-west1, and have tried routing internal traffic only but it doesn't make a difference. Waiting and hoping seems to be the best strategy for now.

Comment: I've just had the same issue. I have removed a bunch (~70 out of ~200) of old revisions and the build went well

Answer (score -2, accepted):

SOLUTION: Just wait a few hours, and it will be back up

Answer (score -7):

delete all your code and `git reset --hard origin/master` worked for me.

originally i `npm i` and still same problem. maybe theres a hidden gcloud data that needed to be deleted.